# Can you ask questions ending with "are you/do you/did you etc."?

Tags: grammaticality, negation, question-tags, is-it-a-rule, conversational-deletion

- Tired, are you?
- Cold outside, is it?
- Seen him around, have you?
- See her, did you?

These sentences might not be grammatical, but I'd like to know if they would be frowned upon.

Answer (score 1):

This is done in speaking in an informal way in many parts of Britain. It is not considered good written or spoken English in other parts of the world. In Britain it is used very informally when speaking and almost never in writing.

Comment: Hello, General. Could you provide more details? What are they called?

Comment: I have only ever heard it used from certain parts of Britain. Primarily the Cockney areas. I'm not sure if that structure has a name. Perhaps its originally a cockney construct.

Comment: The ending question is used often in American English, but in the negative form: "It's cold outside, isn't it?" It's also used when the first question is in the negative: "It isn't cold, is it?"

Comment: Thats true @IsabelArcher however you have significantly altered the structure of the original sentences. In the questioner's example the entire sentence cannot be understood without the section after the comma. In the examples you presented the end question is affirmative of an already understood statement. See: https://www.gymglish.com/en/gymglish/english-grammar/isnt-it